# Initramfs error when apt-get upgrade

Tags: kali-linux, initramfs, error-handling

I'm getting an error everytime i do an apt/apt-get upgrade. I've searched everywhere online for solutions but couldn't find anything

Here's the error i get

**code:**

```
apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  chromium chromium-common chromium-driver chromium-sandbox
  impacket-scripts libavcodec58 libavfilter7 libavformat58 libavutil56
  libheif1 libldb2 libpostproc55 libsmbclient libswresample3 libswscale5
  libwbclient0 open-vm-tools open-vm-tools-desktop powershell-empire
  python3-ldb python3-samba python3-sympy samba samba-common
  samba-common-bin samba-dsdb-modules samba-libs samba-vfs-modules
  smbclient winexe
The following packages will be upgraded:
  apt apt-utils bash binutils binutils-common binutils-x86-64-linux-gnu
  bubblewrap bulk-extractor cifs-utils clang-13 console-setup
  console-setup-linux cpp-11 cron curl debianutils dnsrecon exploitdb
  firebird3.0-common firebird3.0-common-doc firefox-esr firmware-zd1211
  fuse3 g++-11 gcc-11 gcc-11-base gcc-12-base gcr gdal-data
  gir1.2-gstreamer-1.0 gir1.2-gtk-3.0 gir1.2-handy-1
  gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-4.0 gir1.2-nm-1.0 gir1.2-notify-0.7
  gir1.2-pango-1.0 gir1.2-webkit2-4.0 gnome-icon-theme gnome-keyring
  gnome-keyring-pkcs11 gstreamer1.0-gl gstreamer1.0-libav
  gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad gstreamer1.0-plugins-base
  gstreamer1.0-plugins-good gstreamer1.0-x gtk-update-icon-cache gvfs
  gvfs-backends gvfs-common gvfs-daemons gvfs-fuse gvfs-libs
  ibverbs-providers icu-devtools intel-microcode ipp-usb iptables john
  john-data kali-defaults kali-defaults-desktop kali-desktop-base
  kali-desktop-core kali-desktop-live kali-desktop-xfce kali-linux-core
  kali-linux-default kali-linux-firmware kali-linux-headless kali-menu
  kali-themes kali-themes-common kali-tools-top10 keyboard-configuration
  legion lib32gcc-s1 lib32stdc++6 libaom3 libapache2-mod-php8.1
  libappstream4 libapt-pkg6.0 libasan6 libass9 libatomic1 libbinutils
  libblas3 libbluray2 libcaca0 libcc1-0 libcfitsio9
  libcharon-extauth-plugins libclang-common-13-dev libclang-cpp13
  libclang1-13 libctf-nobfd0 libctf0 libcups2 libcurl3-gnutls libcurl4
  libdaxctl1 libdb5.3 libdebconfclient0 libdv4 libdw1 libelf1 libfbclient2
  libfluidsynth3 libfreeaptx0 libfreetype6 libfuse3-3 libgcc-11-dev
  libgcc-s1 libgck-1-0 libgcr-base-3-1 libgcr-ui-3-1 libgdal30 libgfortran5
  libgomp1 libgphoto2-6 libgphoto2-l10n libgphoto2-port12
  libgstreamer-gl1.0-0 libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0
  libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0 libgstreamer1.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libgtk-3-bin
  libgtk-3-common libgtk-4-1 libgtk-4-bin libgtk-4-common libhandy-1-0
  libibverbs1 libicu-dev libicu71 libiec61883-0 libigdgmm12 libindi-data
  libindidriver1 libip4tc2 libip6tc2 libitm1 libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18
  liblapack3 libllvm13 liblsan0 libltdl7 libmbim-glib4 libmbim-proxy
  libmm-glib0 libncurses-dev libncurses5 libncurses6 libncursesw6 libndctl6
  libnghttp2-14 libnginx-mod-http-geoip libnginx-mod-http-image-filter
  libnginx-mod-http-xslt-filter libnginx-mod-mail libnginx-mod-stream
  libnginx-mod-stream-geoip libnm0 libnotify-bin libnotify4 libntfs-3g89
  libobjc-11-dev libobjc4 libodbc2 libodbcinst2 libpam-gnome-keyring
  libpam-modules libpam-modules-bin libpam-runtime libpam0g libpango-1.0-0
  libpangocairo-1.0-0 libpangoft2-1.0-0 libpangoxft-1.0-0 libpcsclite1
  libpipewire-0.3-0 libpipewire-0.3-common libpipewire-0.3-modules libpmem1
  libpod-parser-perl libpq5 libqmi-glib5 libqmi-proxy libquadmath0
  librdmacm1 libsdl2-2.0-0 libsnappy1v5 libsonic0 libspa-0.2-modules
  libspeechd2 libsqlite3-0 libssl1.1 libstdc++-11-dev libstdc++6
  libstrongswan libstrongswan-standard-plugins libtalloc2 libtdb1
  libtevent0 libtiff5 libtinfo-dev libtinfo5 libtinfo6 libtsan0 libubsan1
  libupower-glib3 libv4l-0 libv4lconvert0 libvisual-0.4-0 libvulkan1
  libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37 libwebsockets16 libwireshark-data libwireshark15
  libwiretap12 libwsutil13 libwww-mechanize-perl libwww-perl libxml2
  libxml2-dev libxml2-utils libxtables12 linux-base llvm-13 llvm-13-dev
  llvm-13-linker-tools llvm-13-runtime llvm-13-tools logrotate lsof
  manpages manpages-dev media-types metasploit-framework mitmproxy
  modemmanager nano ncurses-base ncurses-bin ncurses-term network-manager
  network-manager-openconnect network-manager-openconnect-gnome nginx
  nginx-common nginx-core ntfs-3g nvidia-modprobe
  nvidia-tesla-470-alternative nvidia-tesla-470-kernel-support openssl orca
  os-prober pcscd pdf-parser perl-openssl-defaults php8.1 php8.1-cli
  php8.1-common php8.1-mysql php8.1-opcache php8.1-readline pipewire
  pipewire-bin postgresql postgresql-14 postgresql-client-14
  postgresql-client-common postgresql-common python-pastedeploy-tpl
  python3-anyio python3-apispec python3-apscheduler python3-bleach
  python3-blinker python3-bottle python3-cheroot python3-constantly
  python3-debian python3-dicttoxml python3-django python3-dropbox
  python3-feedparser python3-filelock python3-flasgger python3-flaskext.wtf
  python3-future python3-gdal python3-humanize python3-hyperlink
  python3-impacket python3-macholib python3-mako python3-markdown
  python3-marshmallow-sqlalchemy python3-mechanize python3-mypy-extensions
  python3-paste python3-pastedeploy python3-pastescript python3-pip
  python3-pip-whl python3-platformdirs python3-psycopg2
  python3-pyasn1-modules python3-pycurl python3-pyshp
  python3-requests-toolbelt python3-rich python3-speechd python3-talloc
  python3-tdb python3-traitlets python3-twisted python3-zope.deprecation
  python3-zope.interface qemu-guest-agent rsyslog ruby-mini-portile2
  ruby-nokogiri ruby-xmlrpc runit-helper shared-mime-info speech-dispatcher
  speech-dispatcher-audio-plugins speech-dispatcher-espeak-ng spice-vdagent
  sqlite3 sqlmap sslyze strongswan strongswan-charon strongswan-libcharon
  strongswan-starter tango-icon-theme tcpdump tdb-tools tshark
  unixodbc-common unrar upower usb.ids vim vim-common vim-runtime vim-tiny
  vpnc vpnc-scripts wireshark wireshark-common wireshark-qt wordlists
  wpasupplicant xdg-dbus-proxy xdg-desktop-portal xfce4-taskmanager xxd zsh
  zsh-common
365 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 30 not upgraded.
Need to get 769 MB of archives.
After this operation, 14.7 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
...

Installing new version of config file /etc/xdg/autostart/gnome-keyring-ssh.desktop ...
Created symlink /etc/systemd/user/graphical-session-pre.target.wants/gnome-keyring-daemon.service -> /usr/lib/systemd/user/gnome-keyring-daemon.service.
Created symlink /etc/systemd/user/sockets.target.wants/gnome-keyring-daemon.socket -> /usr/lib/systemd/user/gnome-keyring-daemon.socket.
Processing triggers for nvidia-tesla-470-alternative (470.129.06-3) ...
Setting up nvidia-tesla-470-kernel-support (470.129.06-3) ...
Processing triggers for php8.1-cli (8.1.5-1) ...
Processing triggers for libapache2-mod-php8.1 (8.1.5-1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.33-6) ...
Processing triggers for glx-alternative-nvidia (1.2.1) ...
Processing triggers for glx-alternative-mesa (1.2.1) ...
Processing triggers for update-glx (1.2.1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.33-6) ...
Processing triggers for glx-alternative-nvidia (1.2.1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.33-6) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 initramfs-tools
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

The kernel im using

**code:**

```
Linux localhost 5.16.0-kali7-amd64 #1 SMP PREEMPT Debian 5.16.18-1kali1 (2022-04-01) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

version of my kali linux

**code:**

```
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Kali
Description:    Kali GNU/Linux Rolling
Release:        2022.2
Codename:       kali-rolling
```

Can someone help me?

**Thankyou**

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are running out of disk space on `/boot`. You can try to run `apt-get autoremove` before running `apt-get upgrade`.

From the manpage:

> autoremove is used to remove packages that were automatically installed to satisfy dependencies for other packages and are now no longer needed.

This might help as it propably removes dependencies from older kernels, cluttering the FS and preventing a successful run of the `update-initramfs` action.